# The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library was not found on the java.library.path warning in Spring Boot Docker App

Tags: spring-boot, docker, tomcat, native, apr

I see following warning when my Spring Boot App running in Amazon Corretto Docker container-

```
o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
```

Answer (score 0):

Snippet of my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM amazoncorretto:8
RUN yum update -y && yum install -y apr-devel && yum install -y openssl-devel && yum install -y gcc && yum install -y make && yum install -y tar && yum install -y gzip
RUN curl "http://apache.spinellicreations.com/tomcat/tomcat-connectors/native/1.2.23/source/tomcat-native-1.2.23-src.tar.gz" -o ./tomcat-native-1.2.23-src.tar.gz
RUN tar zxf ./tomcat-native-1.2.23-src.tar.gz -C .
RUN cd tomcat-native-1.2.23-src/native/
RUN ./tomcat-native-1.2.23-src/native/configure --with-apr=/usr/bin/apr-1-config --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-amazon-corretto/
RUN make && make install
RUN cp -r /usr/local/apr/lib/* /usr/lib/ 

        .... MORE
```

The above commands added in `Dockerfile` worked for me. Thanks to following resources which helped me find out the commands to add to `Dockerfile`:

[How to install Apache Tomcat Native library](http://blogoless.blogspot.com/2012/08/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-native.html)

[Find out where JAVA is](https://bhargavamin.com/how-to-do/setting-up-java-environment-variable-on-ec2/)

[Tomcat Native / OpenSSL in Spring Boot 2.0](https://medium.com/@crueda/tomcat-native-openssl-in-spring-boot-2-0-a341ad07471d)

I have not run tests to compare the results to see if any improvements yet.